Human-Breathable Volcanic Hydrogen Greenhouse world


Picture 1: How I imagine a life-bearing volcanic Hydrogen world could look like
Picture 2: Topography map of such a world (with black plant life trying to absorb any light it can get)
This paper suggests that molecular Hydrogen could potentially act as a natural indirect greenhouse gas, allowing for habitable surface liquid-ocean bearing worlds much further away from the classic habitable zone than worlds with just Carbon Dioxide or even Methane (up to 2.4 AU around a sun-like star for an atmosphere with ~50% Hydrogen, this could potentially be pushed even further though!).
I would like a Hydrogen world to have Oxygen and be breathable to Humans. But I have ran into a few problems:

Hydrogen and Oxygen react. They form water. If I want to have any substantial Oxygen at all, I will need to increase the atmospheric pressure of the atmosphere so I can have something similar to the gas Hydrox.
If I have Oxygen, especially continuously produced biotic Oxygen, it may destroy the Hydrogen + Methane Greenhouse and plunge the world into an eternal snowball. A temporary snowball called the Huronian Glaciation actually occurred on Earth after the Great Oxidation Event.
Carbon Dioxide. At low insolation, weathering will be slow and worlds this far out will tend to have toxic levels of Carbon Dioxide in their atmospheres. We could suppose native alien life adapt, but this paper suggests complex life may be hindered by such high Carbon Dioxide levels.

Are there ways I can get around these problems and have a volcanic Hydrogen greenhouse world be breathable to humans?

Increasing the atmospheric pressure doesn't make hydrogen any less likely to react with oxygen; Hydrox is still explosive, it just isn't ignited. Breathable volumes of oxygen will react explosively with hydrogen in equal volumes given any ignition source, and you have volcanism!

The ignition and explosive ranges for Hydrogen and Oxygen depend on the ratios used. If I have so much more Hydrogen that per volume Oxygen isn’t enough to start a reaction, then I could use such a mixture to be breathable. It just requires a lot of pressure to have the partial pressure of Oxygen be breathable. This is what divers do with Hydrox.

the flamability range for hydrogen and oxygen mix is between 4%- 75% hydrogen, sorry your not getting around that problem. If there is enough oxygen for humans to breath there is enough for the hydrogen to burn. worse because hydrogen and oxygen have such diffrent densities the air will have high variability in composition. so some areas will hav drastically higher and lower concentrations. sometimes the answer for a sicence based questions is "you can't"

Again, partial pressure matters. If I have low enough Oxygen per volume then the mix will not be flammable. But you did point out something I didn’t take into account, variability at different altitudes. High gravity would also be necessary to reduce the atmospheric scale height.

Hydrogen and oxygen are not compatible in the atmosphere on a long term basis. Apart from potential combustion and explosion at high partial pressures, they would react continually in the atmosphere especially high up in the atmosphere unless they were continuously regenerated in vast quantities.

-Manganese nodules...
Just came across this video - Dark oxygen discovery could change everything!
I'm still searching how this mechanism works. It seems that polymetallic nodules, with particular interest in Manganese-rich nodules, behave like a battery. The presence of many nodules covering the sea floor means that a voltage high enough to generate electrolysis of water is possible. At sea, it is possible that both oxygen and hydrogen are dissolved in water without combusting. This is unlike the conditions in the atmosphere, where oxygen at high enough concentrations to make the atmosphere breathable means an explosive reaction between the two gases. So the water is richer in oxygen. This oxygen can be extracted for use, but this cannot provide a breathable atmosphere "naturally", meaning that some form of technology is needed to extract the oxygen and fill the living quarters.

I like where this is going… but how about the carbon dioxide problem?

As I said, "Some form of technology is needed to extract the oxygen" and that means ensuring there is enough oxygen as well as removing excess carbon dioxide. Some carbon dioxide is still needed in order to support crop culture inside the habitat.

You've got serious difficulties here:
Holding onto a hydrogen atmosphere
You need some combination of high gravity and low temperatures to achieve this. If you want high enough temperatures to allow liquid water, you're going to need several times Earth's gravity to hold onto hydrogen. That makes the world very unattractive, at best, for human habitation.
The paper's suggestion for resolving this problem is continuous replacement of the hydrogen by volcanism. Its mechanism for that is a hypothesis that a planetary mantle starts off in a reduced state and is gradually oxidised, releasing hydrogen to exit the mantle through volcanoes.
I am extremely sceptical of this idea, on conservation-of-mass grounds. Where does 10+% of a planetary mass of oxygen come from?
Atmosphere goes up in flames
If you have significant amounts of free oxygen in a hydrogen atmosphere, any source of ignition, such as volcanism, or simple lightning (which occurs in many kinds of atmosphere) will ignite it. And after the planet-wide explosion you don't have any free oxygen any more.
Yes, you can avoid that by having a very low percentage of oxygen in a high-pressure atmosphere, but are you sure you can restrain life from releasing too much oxygen? The proportion in Earth's atmosphere has varied significantly over geological time.
An engineered biosphere?
The idea of some life being reducing, and some oxidising, to maintain a sufficient partial pressure of oxygen for humans to live, without the atmosphere being an explosive mixture, only really makes sense if the biosphere has been carefully engineered and is being monitored and controlled to maintain these conditions. It would be necessary to keep  the partial pressure of nitrogen very low to avoid narcosis, and that seems very unlikely to happen naturally.
If it's engineered, the question is who did it? They're pretty advanced, since it seems beyond the level of the Ringworld Engineers; the Culture could manage it.

The paper discusses the issue with Hydrogen escape - Hydrogen is outgassed more than it can escape.

Also see my reply to the other user regarding the explosion problem.

@casualworldbuilder: See amended answer.

Perhaps such biotic life would be reducing? Less oxygen is produced as the percentage reaches dangerous levels until it’s lowered again by consumption, which then increases again?

@casualworldbuilder: Further amendments.

An engineered biosphere seems more likely, yup.
